# Multiple image resize and upload with description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, image-resizing

I'm looking for a way to upload multiple images with description. Users will be uploading 1-10 images of quite a large size from cameras so it's better if the images get resized before upload.

Requirements:

- browser compatible (including mobile browsers and IE), can rely on JavaScript (jQuery)
- multiple files either as selection of multiple files in native file manager or at least having to click on some button to bring an input for another file
- add a description to each file
- resize files before upload (doesn't need to be browser compatible)
- uploads on submit
- keeps EXIF info or at least extracts GPS coordinates (could do it with some libraries I found)

Bonuses:

- can auto-rotate image before upload (using EXIF info)
- shows thumbnail of selected image
- drag & drop feature
- progress bar

I use PHP on backend.

I guess HTML5 canvas might be suitable here. Or some jQuery plugin like [blueimp's Jquery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). But I don't have experience with more than simple `<input type="file">`s so I'm asking for your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a more fundamental question in it: can I easily select multiple files (withnout need to click "add another file" button) and add a description to each of the files?

Comment: I would have thought that using HTML5 `canvas` to resize would lose EXIF information, unfortunately.

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried implementing any of the examples from jQuery File Upload? Yes, most of what you want to do is possible, but we can't the code for you. Try and build a demo from the examples, then if you have issues, come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: I'm looking for a direction to go. I could start coding right now but I don't want to reinvent wheel. I tried blueimp's jQuery File Upload but the demo doesn't work in my Android 2.3. So I'd appreciate suggestions from somebody who has experience with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com). Its widget meets almost all of your requirements out of the box, and you can customize it's behavior to cover remaining.

*disclosure*: I am one of Uploadcare developers and am posting this not to shamelessly promote the service but because it was built to solve cases like this one.

Comment: Are you associated with this product? The last four answers you've left all promote it. If so, you need to properly disclose this in these answers or they will be removed for astroturfing.

Comment: I am. Will update answers. Is this written or unwritten rule?

Comment: Written, see the last section here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior . The community here tends to be a little sensitive about self-promotion, because we want people to properly understand the context under which answers are left.

Comment: will disclosure suffice? I do not want to appear as a spammer, and my answers relate to original questions.

Comment: As long as you're clear about it, and the answers directly address the core issue with the question asked. A little more detail on why this would be appropriate for the asker's problem helps, as well.

Comment: should I give fresh answers?

Comment: as for recent answers: one question specifically asked for 3rd party service suggestions, two were in form "how can i do this" and Uploadcare is a way of doing those certain thing, so it;s not just random promotion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46266/discussion-between-mojo-and-brad-larson)